# Как освободить место на диске в virtualbox?

Tags: windows, debian, virtualbox

На физическом носителе установлен virtualbox. место на физическом носителе заканчивается. при удалении файла внутри virtualbox место на физическом диске не освобождается. гостевая ос debian, вопрос как сжать/уменьшить виртуальный диск?

Comment: образы? что?) кто редактирует?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/529149

Comment: сверху правильный ответ, по ссылке хорошая инструкция, мне помогло